# Why must I press Enter TWICE for this JFormattedTextField to activate the JDialog's default button?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

In the code sample below, if a user changes the contents of the JFormattedTextField then presses Enter, the dialog is supposed to act as if the OK button is pressed. But it takes *two* presses of Enter for this to happen.

The plain vanilla JTextField always acts as I would expect - changing the text then pressing Enter activates the OK button straight away.

This in on Mac OS X 10.6 with the current Mac Java update 1.6.0_20.

Is this a work-around? Is this a Mac specific problem?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class ScratchSpace {


    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog((Frame) null, "Test", true);
        dialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        dialog.add(new JLabel("text field: "));
        dialog.add(new JTextField(20));

        dialog.add(new JLabel("formatted text field: "));
        final JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
        formattedTextField.setValue(42);
        formattedTextField.setColumns(20);
        dialog.add(formattedTextField);

        final JButton okButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("OK") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });

        dialog.add(okButton);
        dialog.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this code solved the problem,

```
formattedTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        dialog.dispose();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This did not solve my problem. However, it seemed that the problem solution was much simpler for me:

```
        private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   add(jTextField1);          //this reacts after the "ENTER" gets pressed
   jButton1.doClick();        //this activates the button
   jTextField1.setText("");   //this removes the text from a text-field
  jTextField1.grabFocus();    //this sets a cursor within a text-field
    }
```